# Splitting string with parentheses

Tags: java, regex

I have a list of String that follows this pattern:

```
'Name with space (field1_field2) CONST'
```

Example :

```
'flow gavage(ZAB_B2_COCUM) BS'    
'flowWithoutSpace (WitoutUnderscore) BS'
```

I would like to extract :

- Name with space
- The values inside the brackets
- The CONST value after the brackets

For the string inside the parentheses () I am using :

```
\(.*\)
```

Not sure about the other fields

Comment: Try to `s.split("[()]")` or `s.split("\\s*[()]\\s*")`

Comment: Hey  Wiktor Stribiżew thanks for replying.  tested it here https://regex101.com/ it didn't work

Comment: Really? How did you do it? See [here](https://regex101.com/r/vmJwI0/1)

Comment: My bad..indeed that's what I wanted. Thanks. what about the String inside the brackets (Bla_BLA_Bla). How To get them separately?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? What should be separate?

Comment: I meant that the String inside the '()' like (field1_field2) How to get them separately without the '_'

Comment: Regex ([\w ]*)\(([[\w ]*)\)([[\w ]*) will give you what you want in groups 1, 2 and 3

Comment: You should be more precise about the string format. What are the specs? Can there be `(` or `)` other than around the "bracketed value"? If not, and all your strings come in the format you showed, you will have the `(...)` value in the `results[1]` item (`String[] results = s.split("\\s*[()]\\s*");`).

Comment: Indeed..You are right. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try `split("\\s*[(_)]\\s*")`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
String[] results = s.split("\\s*[()]\\s*");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vmJwI0/1)

**Pattern details**

- `\\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `[()]` - a `)` or `(`
- `\\s*` - 0+ whitespaces

If your strings are always in the format specified (no parentheses, `(...)`, no parentheses), you will have:

```
Name with space                      = results[0]
The values inside the brackets       = results[1]
The CONST value after the brackets   = results[2]
```

If you want a more controlled approach use a matching regex:

```
Pattern.compile("^([^()]*)\\(([^()]*)\\)(.*)$")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vmJwI0/2)

If you use it with `Matcher#matches()`, you may omit `^` and `$` since that method requires a full string match.

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/LFw7Cm):

```
String regex = "^([^()]*)\\(([^()]*)\\)(.*)$";
String s = "flow gavage(ZAB_B2_COCUM) BS";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if (matcher.matches()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1).trim()); 
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2).trim()); 
    System.out.println(matcher.group(3).trim()); 
}
```

Here, the pattern means:

- `^` - start of the string  (implicit in `.matches()`)
- `([^()]*)` - Capturing group 1: any 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\\(` - a `(`
- `([^()]*)` - Capturing group 2: any 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\\)` - a `)`
- `(.*)` - Capturing group 3: any 0+ chars, as many as possible, up to the end of the line (use `([^()]*)` if you need to restrict `(` and `)` in this part, too).
- `$` - end of string (implicit in `.matches()`)

Comment: great, this was what I needed

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:-

```
String line = "'Name with space (field1_field2) CONST'";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Za-z\\s]+)\\((.*)\\)(.*)\\'");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
String nameWithSpace = "";
String fieldsValuesInBrackets = "";
String constantValue = "";

if (matcher.find()) {
    nameWithSpace = matcher.group(1);
    fieldsValuesInBrackets = matcher.group(2);
    constantValue =  matcher.group(3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This expression will generate 3 groups:

```
(.*?)(\(.*?\))\s*?(.*)
```

First group will match name, second one will match values inside brackets, third one will match the constant.